# Ordering Array using a defined order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to format some data for Google Charts.  My initial array is quite large containing quite a bit of data.  As such, I use the reduce function like so

```
const dataFormatted = this.graphData.grouping.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    acc.push([item.category, item.average, this.columnOptions.colors[index], item.average])
    return acc
}, [
    ['category', 'average', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' }]
])
```

So when this is complete, I end up with an array like so

```
[
    ["category","average",{"role":"style"},{"role":"annotation"}],
    ["High",0.0511,"#487090",0.0511],
    ["Low",0.0177,"#EFCA08",0.0177],
    ["Medium",0.03,"#F08700",0.03],
    ["Very High",0.2797,"#FF595E",0.2797],
    ["Very Low",0.0096,"#00A6A6",0.0096]
]
```

The first row will always be what it is, this is for Google Charts.  However, the rows after this, I wanted in the following order

```
const ordering = ['Very Low', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Very High']
```

So I essentially need dataFormatted to end up like this

```
[
    ["category","average",{"role":"style"},{"role":"annotation"}],
    ["Very Low",0.0096,"#00A6A6",0.0096]
    ["Low",0.0177,"#EFCA08",0.0177],
    ["Medium",0.03,"#F08700",0.03],
    ["High",0.0511,"#487090",0.0511],
    ["Very High",0.2797,"#FF595E",0.2797],
]
```

I have tried different things, including checking the value in the reduce function and then using splice on `acc`, but even this seems to go wrong.  My latest attempt is

```
const ordering = ['Very Low', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Very High']
var itemsOrdered = []
for (var i = 0; i < ordering.length; i++) {
  if (dataFormatted.indexOf(ordering[i]) > -1) {
    itemsOrdered.push(ordering[i])
  }
}
console.log(itemsOrdered)
```

But `itemsOrdered` then prints out an empty array.  So what would be the best way to order this array in the way I require?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the array after extracting the values, not while transforming it, *then* add on the first item:

```
const graphData = this.graphData.grouping.map(
    (item, index) => ([item.category, item.average, this.columnOptions.colors[index], item.average])
);
const ordering = ['Very Low', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Very High'];
graphData.sort((a, b) => ordering.indexOf(a[0]) - ordering.indexOf(b[0]));
const headers = ['category', 'average', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' }];
const output = [headers, ...graphData];
```

Comment: Thanks, should it be const output = [headers, ...graphData];  ?

Comment: Oh, absolutely, oops

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the header with an own order.

```js
const
    array = [["category", "average",{"role":"style"},{"role":"annotation"}], ["High",0.0511,"#487090",0.0511], ["Low",0.0177,"#EFCA08",0.0177], ["Medium",0.03,"#F08700",0.03], ["Very High",0.2797,"#FF595E",0.2797], ["Very Low",0.0096,"#00A6A6",0.0096]],
    order = { category: 1, 'Very Low': 2, Low: 3, Medium: 4, High: 5, 'Very High': 6 };

array.sort(([a], [b]) => order[a] - order[b]);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```